# The number of FixedLocator locations (11), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (166) | Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I posted a question previously but my wording got it flagged as a duplicate, so I'll be super specific on this one.

This is 13 rows of data, but my df has about 160:

```
Animal  Score
0   Dog 1
1   Pig 2
2   Chicken 3
3   Cat 4
4   Fox 5
5   Whale 6
7   Beetle 7
8   Ox 8
9   Monkey 9
10  Cow 10
11  Duck 11
12  Hen 12
13  Crow 13
```

I'm trying to annotate a graph with the values, and there is one line of code that's buggin' out on me and I cannot figure out why - `ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)`

I think it's because of the concat that's forcing 11 rows instead of the full 160 odd, but here's the code:

```
#Add custom entries here
custom_df = dfAnimalRankings.loc[dfAnimalRankings['Animals'].isin(['Beetle'])]

# Create new df to show top 5, bottom 5, and Beetle
new_df = pd.concat([dfAnimalRankings[:5], dfAnimalRankings[-5:], custom_df])
new_df.sort_values(by=['Score'], inplace= True)
new_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace= True)

# Plot the figure.
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
ax = new_df.plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_title('Animal Rankings')
ax.set_xlabel('Animals')
ax.set_ylabel('Score')
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)

rects = ax.patches

def add_value_labels(ax, spacing=5):
    """Add labels to the end of each bar in a bar chart.

    Arguments:
        ax (matplotlib.axes.Axes): The matplotlib object containing the axes
            of the plot to annotate.
        spacing (int): The distance between the labels and the bars.
    """

    # For each bar: Place a label
    for rect in ax.patches:
        # Get X and Y placement of label from rect.
        y_value = rect.get_height()
        x_value = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2

        # Number of points between bar and label. Change to your liking.
        space = spacing
        # Vertical alignment for positive values
        va = 'bottom'

        # If value of bar is negative: Place label below bar
        if y_value < 0:
            # Invert space to place label below
            space *= -1
            # Vertically align label at top
            va = 'top'

        # Use Y value as label and format number with one decimal place
        label = "{:.1f}".format(y_value)

        # Create annotation
        ax.annotate(
            label,                      # Use `label` as label
            (x_value, y_value),         # Place label at end of the bar
            xytext=(0, space),          # Vertically shift label by `space`
            textcoords="offset points", # Interpret `xytext` as offset in points
            ha='center',                # Horizontally center label
            va=va)                      # Vertically align label differently for
                                        # positive and negative values.


# Call the function above. All the magic happens there.
add_value_labels(ax)

plt.savefig("image.png")
```

If I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
The number of FixedLocator locations (11), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (166).
```

But if I run this code:

```
#Add custom entries here
custom_df = dfAnimalRankings.loc[dfAnimalRankings['Animals'].isin(['Beetle'])]

# Create new df to show top 5, bottom 5, and Beetle
new_df = pd.concat([dfAnimalRankings[:5], dfAnimalRankings[-5:], custom_df])
new_df.sort_values(by=['Score'], inplace= True)
new_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace= True)

# Plot the figure.
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
ax = new_df.plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_title('Animal Rankings')
ax.set_xlabel('Animals')
ax.set_ylabel('Score')
# ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)

rects = ax.patches

def add_value_labels(ax, spacing=5):
    """Add labels to the end of each bar in a bar chart.

    Arguments:
        ax (matplotlib.axes.Axes): The matplotlib object containing the axes
            of the plot to annotate.
        spacing (int): The distance between the labels and the bars.
    """

    # For each bar: Place a label
    for rect in ax.patches:
        # Get X and Y placement of label from rect.
        y_value = rect.get_height()
        x_value = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2

        # Number of points between bar and label. Change to your liking.
        space = spacing
        # Vertical alignment for positive values
        va = 'bottom'

        # If value of bar is negative: Place label below bar
        if y_value < 0:
            # Invert space to place label below
            space *= -1
            # Vertically align label at top
            va = 'top'

        # Use Y value as label and format number with one decimal place
        label = "{:.1f}".format(y_value)

        # Create annotation
        ax.annotate(
            label,                      # Use `label` as label
            (x_value, y_value),         # Place label at end of the bar
            xytext=(0, space),          # Vertically shift label by `space`
            textcoords="offset points", # Interpret `xytext` as offset in points
            ha='center',                # Horizontally center label
            va=va)                      # Vertically align label differently for
                                        # positive and negative values.


# Call the function above. All the magic happens there.
add_value_labels(ax)

plt.savefig("image.png")
```

I get this (I'm aware the numbers don't match, but it's an output from my actual dataset not the sample above):

[image]

Why does that one line of code break the annotation? And how can I get the data labels, which are animal names and not the numbers, added to the chart?

Cheers

Comment: I don't see `x_labels` defined anywhere

Comment: good point, but adding in `x_labels = dfAnimalRankings['Animals'].tolist()

# Plot the figure.
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
ax = new_df.plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_title('Animal Rankings')
ax.set_xlabel('Animals')
ax.set_ylabel('Score')
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)` still gives me `The number of FixedLocator locations (11), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (166).` when run so I can't confirm if it worked or not?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Make sure you're updated to `matplotlib v3.4.2`, remove your entire function and use `ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], label_type='edge')` as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804)

Comment: I removed everything from `rects =ax.patches` down to `add_value_labels(ax)` and replaced it with `ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], label_type='edge')` and got this error message `'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'bar_label'` Edit: I'm running 3.3.4, which is why.

Comment: Updated and that worked amazingly - thank you so much for the super simple tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're getting an error is clear, your plot has only 11 bars but you're passing 166 labels to them. My guess is you've mixed up your `dfAnimalRankings` and `new_df` as a result you've got mismatched labels.

The workaround here would be to set `x_labels` to

```
x_labels = new_df['Animals'].tolist()
```

That way you'll get exactly 11 labels for 11 bars.